# Как пишутся "дисторш(е)н", "экш(е)н" и т. п.?

Tags: орфография, склонение, падежи, английский-язык, склоняемость

1. Как я посмотрел в ответах Майл.ру, большинство там пишет данные слова в прямом, или именительном, падеже почему-то без буквы Е таки. Разве в таких словах не должна быть буква Е, если при склонении этих англицизмов данная гласная выдаёт себя: distortion'e - дисторшЕне?
2. Англицизмы - это произошедшие из английского языка слова.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, в чём заключается ваш вопрос.

Comment: 1. В том, чтобы узнать то, как правильно на самом деле писать.

Comment: Я поправил ваш вопрос, добавив вопрос и убрав  в данном случае излишние  уточнения. Если вы не согласны с правкой, хотите что-то изменить или добавить в вопрос или ответ, может воспользоваться кнопкой править под ними.

Comment: @Марк_Из_♦ 1. Ага.

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, у большинства таких слов мало шансов на полноценное *заимствование* - с возможностью склонения и широкого употребления в письменном виде. Единственное распространившееся де-факто исключение, которое приходит на ум, это "**ресепшен**" (приёмная стойка администратора отеля). По всей видимости, "**е**" прижилось именно в интересах склонения слова, удобного для речевых сокращений. Прочие такие слова переносятся как термины с другим окончанием (напр. **дисторсия** в оптике) или транскрибируются в элементы названий фирм (**корпорейшн**, **органайзейшн**), которые в составе сложных названий используются *совместно с видовым наименованием* и не склоняются (это же применимо и к музыкальной "примочке" или звуковому эффекту "дисторшн"). Способ транскрипции таких окончаний традиционно ориентировался на британское произношение, в североамериканском же диалекте многие такие слова произносятся без редукции гласной в последнем слове (например, session "сэшн/сэшен"; в русском музыкальном жаргоне и вовсе "сейшен" и "сейшенА" во мн. числе). В случаях, когда в английском оригинале требуется отчётливое произношение (особенности музыкального произведения и т. п. - можно услышать напр. в опере Quadrophenia), то -ion произносится с гласным звуком, близким  к "о", а не к "е".

Comment: 1. То есть без гласной то, что в вопросе, слово должно быть?